# Jquery - Loop each Selected Option

Tags: jquery, local-storage, each

I have a very simple form that contains a select dropdown list.

```
<select name ='select[]' id='select' class='select'>
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>2</option>
</select>
```

Using Jquery I have a button that when clicked clones this select and removes the ID.

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var $new = $('#row').clone(true).removeAttr('id');
    $new.find('*').andSelf().removeAttr('id');
    $('#tbl_test tr:last').before($new);
    return false;
});
```

on submitting the form I'm getting the correct data back from select[]

What I'd like to do is write this information to localStorage by looping through all selects that have been created using the class 'select'

I've tried this :

```
$('.select').each(function(index,item){
    localStorage.setItem('new',item);
});
```

but item doesn't return the selected entry from the dropdowns, but the full dropdown list..

Any idea how I can do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using $('.select') you are selecting a single DOM element (and its children).  You need just the children.  Try:

```
$('.select').children().each(function(index,item){
    localStorage.setItem('new',item);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that - but I'm still getting all of the full options returned, no the individual selected item.  Any idea why ?

Comment: Here is a fiddle. I don't have your full example code, but take a look and I think you can extrapolate this to what you need. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuvvm3j3/)

Comment: thanks but i'm still getting all the options back not just the selected one.  this is what I get `iteration
<option value="1">1</option>
iteration
<option value="2">2</option>
iteration
<option value="3">3</option>
iteration`   What I'm hoping to get is if option 2 is selected then I get the value of option 2.

Comment: Changing the JQuery to this works in that it returns the values selected.
`$('#add').click(function() {
    $('.select option:selected').each(function(index,item){
        console.log( $(item).text() );
    });
});`

FIDDLE Here http://jsfiddle.net/uuvvm3j3/3/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really show all the html that is being affected in your example but

```
$('.select').each(function(index,item){
    localStorage.setItem('new',item);
});
```

needs to get changed to

```
$('.select option').each(function(index,item){
    localStorage.setItem('new',item);
});
```

The first piece of code just selects the select box not it's children so you need to make sure you ask for the options of the select box not the select box itself.

Comment: That seems to return the same as my test, in that I get all the result back not the individual selected item.